# Fixing npm install vulnerabilities manually gulp-sass, node-sass

Tags: npm, gulp, gulp-sass, node-sass

I'm getting the following moderate vulnerabilities when I try to install gulp-sass and node-sass to my local git project. I've already installed gulp version 4.0.

I have installed the latest version of hoek, 5.0.3 and tried to install gulp-sass and node-sass after installing the packages but it is still showing the vulnerabilites. How can I manually fix this? Is there a way to fix the files?

---

Vulnerabilities:

Moderate        Prototype pollution

Package         hoek

Patched in      > 4.2.0 < 5.0.0 || >= 5.0.3

Dependency of   gulp-sass

Path            gulp-sass > node-sass > node-gyp > request > hawk > boom >
                  hoek

More info       https://nodesecurity.io/advisories/566

Moderate        Prototype pollution

Package         hoek

Patched in      > 4.2.0 < 5.0.0 || >= 5.0.3

Dependency of   gulp-sass

Path            gulp-sass > node-sass > node-gyp > request > hawk >
                  cryptiles > boom > hoek

More info       https://nodesecurity.io/advisories/566

Moderate        Prototype pollution

Package         hoek

Patched in      > 4.2.0 < 5.0.0 || >= 5.0.3

Dependency of   gulp-sass

Path            gulp-sass > node-sass > node-gyp > request > hawk > hoek

More info       https://nodesecurity.io/advisories/566

Moderate        Prototype pollution

Package         hoek

Patched in      > 4.2.0 < 5.0.0 || >= 5.0.3

Dependency of   gulp-sass

Path            gulp-sass > node-sass > node-gyp > request > hawk > sntp >
                  hoek

More info       https://nodesecurity.io/advisories/566

Moderate        Prototype pollution

Package         hoek

Patched in      > 4.2.0 < 5.0.0 || >= 5.0.3

Dependency of   node-sass

Path            node-sass > node-gyp > request > hawk > boom > hoek

More info       https://nodesecurity.io/advisories/566

Moderate        Prototype pollution

Package         hoek

Patched in      > 4.2.0 < 5.0.0 || >= 5.0.3

Dependency of   node-sass

Path            node-sass > node-gyp > request > hawk > cryptiles > boom >
                  hoek

More info       https://nodesecurity.io/advisories/566

Moderate        Prototype pollution

Package         hoek

Patched in      > 4.2.0 < 5.0.0 || >= 5.0.3

Dependency of   node-sass

Path            node-sass > node-gyp > request > hawk > hoek

More info       https://nodesecurity.io/advisories/566

Moderate        Prototype pollution

Package         hoek

Patched in      > 4.2.0 < 5.0.0 || >= 5.0.3

Dependency of   node-sass

Path            node-sass > node-gyp > request > hawk > sntp > hoek

More info       https://nodesecurity.io/advisories/566

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, your project contains dependencies which are in-turn dependent on the vulnerable version of hoek package. After searching through several issues in github such as

- https://github.com/dlmanning/gulp-sass/issues/687
- https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/2288
- https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/2355

And finally, found that the issue will only be fixed in the v5 release of node-sass https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/2111. So you need to wait for the latest release of node-sass with the fix after which gulp-sass should also be updated to use the v5 of node-sass to fully fix the issue.

There are plenty of projects like this that are suffering prototype pollution because they are unable to upgrade the vulnerable versions of affected packages such as hoek.

I created **[no-pollution](https://www.npmjs.com/package/no-pollution)** library for the people who are exactly facing this issue. You can install it and include `require('no-pollution')` in the entry point of your project to prevent any prototype pollution attacks from happening even if you have a vulnerable package installed.